# Obtener la posición del numero mayor de una lista de derecha a izquierda

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista

soy nuevo en esto de programar. Agradezco que me puedan ayudar con este problema:

Tengo una lista en la que quisiera imprimir la posición del valor mínimo (en caso de repetirse) de izquierda a derecha, y la del valor máximo (en caso de repetirse) de derecha a izquierda. Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
lista = [12,56,-22,56,24,-4,-80,2,-34,-74]

val_min = min(lista)
pos_min = lista.index(lista)

val_max = max(lista)
pos_max = lista.index(max(lista[::-1]))

print ("valor minimo = ",val_min,"posicion minima del valor = ",pos_min)
print ("valor maximo = ", val_max,"posicion maxima del valor = ",pos_max)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, debes buscar el índice del valor máximo en la lista invertida no en la original, en vez de :

```
lista.index(max(lista[::-1]))
```

debe ser:

```
lista[::-1].index(max(lista))
```

Luego solo tienes que realizar una simple operación aritmética para convertir dicho índice al que el elemento tiene en la lista original:

```
lista = [12,56,-22,56,24,-4,-80,2,-34,-74]

val_min = min(lista)
pos_min = lista.index(val_min)

val_max = max(lista)
pos_max = len(lista) - lista[::-1].index(val_max) - 1

print ("valor minimo = ",val_min,"posicion minima del valor = ",pos_min)
print ("valor maximo = ", val_max,"posicion maxima del valor = ",pos_max)
```

Salida:

> ```
> valor minimo =  -80 posicion minima del valor =  6
> valor maximo =  56 posicion maxima del valor =  3
> ```

Invertir la lista usando rebanado implica crear una nueva lista lo cual podría ser contraproducente en algunos casos si la lista es muy extensa (aunque al tratarse de una copia superficial el consumo de memoria es relativamente contenido), esto puede evitarse implementando nuestro propio `rindex` (como tienen las cadenas):

```
def rindex(lista, item):
    for index, list_item in enumerate(reversed(lista)):
        if list_item == item:
            return len(lista) - index - 1
    raise ValueError(f"{item} is not in list")

lista = [12, 56, -22, 56, 24, -4, -80, 2, -34, -74]

val_min = min(lista)
pos_min = lista.index(val_min)
val_max = max(lista)
pos_max = rindex(lista, val_max)

print(f"Valor minimo: {val_min}, posición mínima del valor: {pos_min}")
print(f"Valor maximo: {val_max}, posición máxima del valor: {pos_max}")
```

`reversed` retorna un iterador que permite iterar la lista en orden inverso sin crear un nuevo objeto.